# Unable to locate text element in aria-label with the XPath expression

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to automate process of filling website security questions presented after login. Two questions are randomly presented from a pool of 6 questions I've already answered.

Every Xpath option I've tried to identify the specific security  question asked found in the 'aria-label' element returns `NoSuchElementException`.

I've tried many methods down the google rabbit hole including:

```
#First Attempt
question_1=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@label="name of first employer?"]')

#Second Attempt 
question_1=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@label="name of first employer?"]/label[text()="name of first employer?"]')
```

I've included html of inspected element for two security questions below:

```
<input type="password" name="first_security_question" aria-label="Unique pin #4" value="">

<input type="password" name="second_security_question" aria-label="Model of first car?" value="">
```

I expect to identify the specific question in the aria-label so I can send appropriate keys to fill the form question but instead all I get is `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the question then do the following.

```
# get the question 1 element
questionEle=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='first_security_question']")
# get the question
question_1 = questionEle.get_attribute("aria-label")
```

Then get the answer for the question and send the input to question.

Comment: if you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the downvote button in my answer on the left hand side.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but got same exception error "NoSuchElementException"

Comment: Updated suggestion didn't work. My code is here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zqb2MrimYb_gV2YmyBEc2AM8IKxNdHWO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have to change the `questionEle` line code to match with my answer. The problem with your current approach is, when `name of first employer?` is not part of the 2 questions (out of 6) then you will get NoSuchElement exception. That's the reason why you should get the question by getting `aria-label` based on `name`